# Authenticated Vapor session not preserved inside an XCTest

Tags: swift, xctest, vapor

The application itself works fine, but I can't get a test to work that confirms this.

In Part 1 below, the test checks that the login using email and (correct) password succeeds and the correct URL redirection is returned. In the code immediately before the redirection returns to the test, debug shows that a call to `request.auth.require(User.self)` succeeds.

In both Parts 2a and 2b, the `XCTAssertEqual` fails and the log shows that the result of the call to `request.auth.require(User.self)` has thrown an error saying the user is not authorised.

Part 3 is a double-check that Part 1 is working as it, too, returns the correct URL redirection for an unsuccessful login.

So, it seems that the session data is not being preserved beyond the call to `.test(...)`. Is there a way around this?

```
@testable import App
import XCTVapor
final class AppTests: XCTestCase
{
    func test011UserLoginLogout() throws
    {
        func attemptLogin(withPassword password:String, completion:(XCTHTTPResponse) throws -> ()) throws -> Void
        {
            var body = ByteBufferAllocator().buffer(capacity: 0)
            body.writeString(#"{"email":"me@example.com","password":"\#(password)"}"#)
            var headers = HTTPHeaders()
            headers.replaceOrAdd(name: .contentLength, value: body.readableBytes.description)
            headers.contentType = .json
            try app.test(.POST, "/login", headers:headers, body:body) { response in try completion( response ) }
        }

        var app = Application(.testing)
        app.databases.use(.mysql(hostname:DBHost, username:DBAccount, password:DBPassword, database:DBDatabase, tlsConfiguration:.none), as:.mysql)
        app.databases.default(to:.mysql)
        do { try configure(app!) }
        catch { XCTFail("configure(app) failed") }
        //  Part 1 succeeds
        try attemptLogin(withPassword:"goodPassword")
        {
            res in
            XCTAssertEqual(res.status, HTTPResponseStatus.seeOther)
            XCTAssertEqual(res.headers["location"].first,"success")
            try app!.test(.GET, "/success")
            {
                response in
                XCTAssertEqual(response.status, .ok) // <--- Part 2(a) fails
            }
        }

        try app.test(.GET, "/success")
        {
            response in
            XCTAssertEqual(response.status, .ok) // <-- Part 2(b) fails
        }

        // Part 3 succeeds
        try attemptLogin(withPassword:"badPassword")
        {
            response in
            XCTAssertEqual(response.status, .seeOther)
            XCTAssertEqual(response.headers["location"].first,"failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the authentication in the request that are failing. You either need to pass the session cookie into the failing request if using sessions or the token if using bearer auth.

Comment: Thanks, @0xTim. Interesting, I'll have a look. I might be able to capture the cookie from the response to the login post test and then pass it on manually.

Comment: A step along the way, @0xTim! I've got the session cookie now passed into the request headers, but it is still failing because there is no session property in XCTHTTPRequest.

Comment: Yeah that's the way to go, take the login cookie (normally under `vapor-session` from the login response and add it to future requests. Otherwise the requests you're trying to send are no different from an unauthenticated request. [Here's an example](https://github.com/brokenhandsio/SteamPress/blob/vapor4/Tests/SteamPressTests/Helpers/TestWorld%2BResponses.swift#L25) that does that (but not using XCTVapor)

Comment: Switch to discord, @OxTim? I can set the cooke, no problem, but it then uses this to look up the _UserSession value in the session data.