# How Does Testing In Vapor 4 Incorporate Sessions?

Tags: swift, testing, vapor

I have a series of tests of an http/html (not JSON) server in Vapor. One creates a user in the Users db, then logs in using a POST request, to confirm that the user exists, with a positive response:

```
2021-06-17T13:17:43+0700 info codes.vapor.request : request-id=97BBFF64-52B8-4988-BA79-236A43C0212F POST /test/login/
logged in stressed_tangerine_hedgehog@sillyname.org
```

If I do the same thing manually using the running server, on the development database, I get the same positive result, and the cookie is there: (using Thunder Client):

[image: screen shot of Thunder Client]

[image: screen shot of Thunder Client]

If I then hit a testing endpoint, a simple get that indicates if there is a session user, also using ThunderClient, the user exists.

But when, in the testing environment, I follow the login with a request to the same endpoint, I get no user:

```
2021-06-17T13:17:43+0700 info codes.vapor.request : request-id=5D8FA5FC-B176-4355-9A37-FAE01772A1C6 GET /test/
not logged in
```

The testing endpoint looks like this:

```
   func getTestHandler(req: Request) -> String {
        guard let user = req.auth.get(User.self) else {
            print("not logged in")
            return "not logged in"
        }
        print(user.username)
        return "got the handler"
    }
```

…and the messages that are returned are correct in Thunder Client.

Is it the case that XCTAssert testing in the Vapor testing environment doesn't implement any form of session cookies, and if not, is there a work around? If it does, what do I have to do to get them to work?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62084102/authenticated-vapor-session-not-preserved-inside-an-xctest I followed up on discord with 0xTim and it seems that they weren't implemented at the time. I haven't checked recently. HTH

Answer (score 1):

It's your responsibility to capture the cookie set in the login response and send it with subsequent requests in your tests

Answer (score 0):

The first method is the one that gets called when you need to access a logged-in route in a test. `loggedInUser` and `passwordToLoginWith` are the user that will be authenticated. `body` provides an context you need for the eventual call. `loginPath` in `setLoginCookie` is your authentication endpoint. The rest should be self explanatory.

```
extension UserTests {
    
    func getResponse<T: Content>(to path: String,
                        method: HTTPMethod = .POST,
                        body: T,
                        loggedInUser: User? = nil,
                        passwordToLoginWith: String? = nil,
                        headers: HTTPHeaders = .init()) throws -> Response {
        let request = try setupRequest(to: path,
                        method: method,
                        loggedInUser: loggedInUser,
                        passwordToLoginWith: passwordToLoginWith,
                        headers: headers)
        
        try request.content.encode(body)
        return try getResponse(to: request)
    }
    
    
    func getResponse(to path: String,
                     method: HTTPMethod = .GET,
                     headers: HTTPHeaders = .init(),
                     loggedInUser: User? = nil) throws -> Response {
        let request = try setupRequest(to: path, method: method, loggedInUser: loggedInUser, passwordToLoginWith: stdPass, headers: headers)
        return try getResponse(to: request)
    }
    
    func setupRequest(to path: String,
                      method: HTTPMethod = .POST,
                      loggedInUser: User? = nil,
                      passwordToLoginWith: String? = nil,
                      headers: HTTPHeaders = .init()) throws -> Request {
            let request = Request(application: app,
                      method: method,
                      url: URI(path: path),
                      headers: headers, on:app.eventLoopGroup.next())
            request.cookies["vapor-session"] = try setLoginCookie(for: loggedInUser, password: passwordToLoginWith)
            return request
    }
    
    func setLoginCookie(for user: User?, password: String? = nil) throws -> HTTPCookies.Value? {
        if let user = user {
            let loginData = TestController.LoginContext(username: user.username, password: password!, email: user.username)
            let loginPath = "/test/login"

            let loginResponse = try getResponse(to: loginPath, method: .POST, body: loginData)
            let sessionCookie = loginResponse.cookies["vapor-session"]
            return sessionCookie
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func getResponse(to request: Request) throws -> Response {
        return try app.responder.respond(to: request).wait()
    }
}
```

This is more or less as found in a Github project, link provided by 0xTim. That was really useful (until it disappeared into the flow of the Vapor Discord server; Vapor's community loses a great deal because of the ephemeral way that community questions and answers disappear into Discord's black maw.)